# manage.py runserver stuck(without errors)

Tags: django, python-3.x

when i add to `__init__.py` line `default_app_config = 'component.nodes.apps.NodesConfig'` apps file have next code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class NodesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'component.nodes'

    def ready(self):
        from component.nodes import signals
```

Django `manage.py runserver` stuck and don't send any error if i press ctrl-c i receiveed nex traceback:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):


File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/storj/storj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/storj/storj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 318, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/storj/storj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/storj/storj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line
27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/storj/storj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/storj/storjboard_server/component/nodes/apps.py", line 8, in ready
    from component.nodes import signals
  File "/home/storj/storjboard_server/component/nodes/signals.py", line 5, in <module>
    from component.nodes.tasks import node_info_update
  File "/home/storj/storjboard_server/component/nodes/tasks.py", line 5, in <module>
    from server.celery import app
  File "/home/storj/storjboard_server/server/celery.py", line 10, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/storj/storj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/storj/storj/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 71, in populate
    with self._lock:
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: this line `from component.nodes import signals` stands for what?. the traceback that you have is a normal one when you interrupt the server with ctrl+c

Comment: are you sure that you have `signals` inside your `component.nodes` app?

Comment: 1) coment to import signal from file signals.py,

Comment: yes there signal.py with signals

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue the issue was that in signals.py i use celery async task, and celery wasn't setup correctly